# How to send media keys like "pause" or sth with python keyboard?

Tags: python, keyboard

What should be in the brackets: `keyboard.send( ? )`

Comment: Try to read [the docs](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.send).

Comment: There's no list of keys or something else that would help me

; They just mention the media Keys in context with - 

`"Known Limitations: Media keys on Linux may appear nameless (scan-code only) or not at all"`

Comment: But you can easily google scan codes list [*(just first entry from google)*](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/current/rtl/keyboard/kbdscancode.html).